# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest completionHandler logs appearing before updating the UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, sendasynchronousrequest

I have this code to send a json string to a server

```
[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:req
 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                     NSData *data,
                     NSError *error)
 {

     if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
     {

         NSLog(@"Done");

     }
     else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
         self.resultLabel.text=@"Done!";
         self.view.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
     }
     else if (error != nil){
         NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
     }


 }];
```

The asynchronous request finishes fine and the logs show up almost immediately after it is finished.  However, this code:

```
self.resultLabel.text=@"Done!";
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

Takes a good 10 seconds to show up in the UI.  Anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 12):

You must perform all UI changes in main thread:

```
....
if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.resultLabel.text=@"Done!";
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    });
}
....
```

Comment: Yes, it has to be that way! Thanks. Saved my day :)